# Opposite of pop-tag-mark

Tags: ctags

I just found out about the function `pop-tag-mark` (`M-*` by default) to go back after a `find-tag` (or in this case after a `racer-find-definition`).

Occasionally I would like to go "forward" again after going back with `pop-tag-mark`. Is this possible in an easy way, or would I have to write a bunch of ELisp to do this?

Basically what I want is something similar to Back/Forward in your web browser.

Comment: Not directly — you'll need to advise `pop-tag-mark`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but I recently found out about [forward-backward-mode](https://gitlab.com/vancan1ty/emacs-backward-forward/) and it has solved my use case pretty well.

It's also available on [Melpa](http://www.melpa.org).